# Why is my responsive background image leaving white space at the bottom of the image?

Tags: html, css

I have a responsive image which is leaving white space under the image when resizing the browser. I tried cover but the image doesn't resize at all only setting the background to 100% gives perfect responsiveness. I tried multiple other solutions from stack overflow and none seem to work.

error here :https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxHtDrLLi2x5ckJNMVVNblRSSWc

css:

```
  #jumbotron{
  text-align:center;
  background-color:#71706e;
  padding-top:80px;
  width:100%;
  background: url(images/showcase5.jpg) no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
 }
```

html:

```
<section id = "jumbotron">
  <div class="text">
    <h1 class="animated slideInDown">Now now now!</h1>
    <h2 class="animated slideInDown">Now now now now<br> before your now do!</h2>
    <a href="#" class="learnMore " >Get Started</a>
  </div>
</section>
<div id="recent">
  <h3>Recent Projects</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want the entire image to fit the white space or the other way around?

Comment: If your image has a larger aspect ratio than the element (i.e. too wide, not enough height), then setting background-size to 100% will only cause it to fit the width. If you want it to cover the element completely, use `background-size: cover`.

Comment: i want to view the whole image just smaller when i resize and i also want the white space to be removed and the content to join the image. When i use cover the image isnt responsive any more but the space is filled

Comment: So you want the container to be the same aspect ratio as the background image? You have to realise that this is an either-or scenario: you can't have the image fitting perfectly, be responsive, and yet not be cropped/letterboxed.

Comment: @Terry I want the image to be responsive like the one on this website https://www.studio22.com/

Comment: If you bothered to look into their code you will realise that they are using JS to set the height of the image container. Basically, if you want the element to respect the aspect ratio of the background image, you need to explicitly set the height. If you want the background image to fill the element with an unknown aspect ratio, then you need to accept that it will be cropped.

Comment: what are the dimensions on the background image?

Comment: The dimensions are 1920 * 1265

Comment: how is the `.text` section supposed to look/display over the background?

Comment: center of the background image

Comment: horizontal and vertical center or just horizontal?

Comment: just horizontal centered

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general concept is to set the `height` of the container to 0 and use a vertical padding that matches the background image aspect ratio. To get that padding, divide the image height by the width and multiply by 100 to get a percentage. Then the div will scale the same as the background image. And just set the background size to 100%, contain, or cover.

```css
#jumbotron {
  background: url('http://placehold.it/1920x1265') 0 0 no-repeat / cover;
  padding-bottom: 65.89%;
  height: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<section id = "jumbotron">
  <div class="text">
    <h1 class="animated slideInDown">Now now now!</h1>
    <h2 class="animated slideInDown">Now now now now<br> before your now do!</h2>
    <a href="#" class="learnMore " >Get Started</a>
  </div>
</section>
<div id="recent">
  <h3>Recent Projects</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow thanks so much i spent days trying to get this to work. I will have to spend some time trying to understand how this works though its making my head hurt. Thanks again Michael!

Comment: @J.Pillonin no sweat. for what it's worth, I learned the technique here for making responsive youtube videos. https://css-tricks.com/NetMag/FluidWidthVideo/Article-FluidWidthVideo.php

Comment: @J.Pillonin this technique requires that the element be `position:relative` (*if it has contents*) and these contents need to be `position:absolute` other wise the padding and the contents size add-up and it looses the ratio.

Comment: additionally the `padding` trick will not work directly on the element if that element does not fill its own container 100%. So it is advised to use a pseudo-element like `:before` to set the padding. That is because the percentage padding is in relation to the container's width and not its own width.

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli in some cases, yeah. But did you look at my example? The parent has children and nothing is relative/absolute, and the parent doesn't expand beyond the image ratio padding.

Comment: @MichaelCoker, a yes. Just noticed the `height:0`. Cool trick. I wonder if there are cases this might misbehave. (*The issue with the container though still stands, so no width for that element.*)

Comment: (*btw the original comment was meant to be directed to you @MichaelCoker and not the OP, sorry about that*)